# Converting all RGB to one pixel decimal value

Tags: php, gd, pixel

I have the following code that convert an image pixel to corresponding RGB Values, what I want now is to convert all the RGB values to one decimal number that is normally returned by imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y),After trying diff. ways and searching the web, I havent been able to come up with a way, I hope one can provide me with a simple way.

```
<?php

$resource = imagecreatefrompng("c.png");

$pixelValue=imagecolorat($resource, 1, 1); // this normally return something as 402399

// but after performing this

$r = ($PixelsValue >> 16) & 0xFF; // result will be $r= 16

$g = ($PixelsValue>> 8) & 0xFF; // result will be $g=123

$b = $PixelsValue& 0xFF; // result will be $b=200

// now I want to return $r= 16,$g=123 and $b=200 to 402399
```

?>

Comment: looks pretty straight forward? Just run the opposite bit shifts: `($r << 16) + ($g << 8) + $b`?

Comment: how @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: By reading up on how to use bit operations, apparently. If you've never seen `<<` or the like, head over to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php and read through that a bit first, to understand why the code you're showing even works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base_convert, documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php).
You are converting from Hexadecimal values to decimal, quite straightforward.

```
<?php
$r = '16';
$g = '123';
$b = '200';
$r = base_convert($r, 10, 16);
$g = base_convert($g, 10, 16);
$b = base_convert($b, 10, 16);
$value = $r.$g.$b;
echo $value; //will output 107bc8
?>
```